# How do I structure data for Ext.DataView?

Tags: json, sencha-touch, extjs

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459656/sencha-touch-ext-dataview-not-showing-store-data), I can't get my DataView to actually show data. I tried to restructure my store, but I think I'm missing something. Here's what I've got so far:

**App, Model, Store**

```
Ext.regApplication({
    name: 'TestApp',
    launch: function() {
        this.viewport = new TestApp.views.Viewport();
    }
});

TestApp.models.StoreMe = Ext.regModel('TestApp.models.StoreMe', {
    fields: [
        'id',
        'name',
        'age'
    ]
});

TestApp.stores.storeMe = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'TestApp.models.StoreMe',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

**Viewport and DataView**

```
TestApp.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'card',
    items: [
        {
            id: 'dataView',
            xtype: 'dataview',
            store: TestApp.stores.storeMe,
            itemSelector: 'div.dataViewItem',
            emptyText: 'NO DATA',
            tpl: '<tpl for "."><div class="dataViewItem">ID: {id}<br />Name: {name}<br />Age: {age}</div></tpl>'
        }
    ]
});
```

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "sam",
        "age": "4"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "jack",
        "age": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "danny",
        "age": "12"
    }
]
```

Any ideas? All of the other questions that are similar to this use Ext.JsonStore, but the Sencha API docs say to do it this way.

**UPDATE**

The store is working fine. Here's what `TestApp.stores.storeMe.data` looks like:

```
Ext.util.MixedCollection
    ...
    items: Array[3]
        0: c
            data: Object
                age: "4"
                id: "1"
                name: "sam"
        1: c
        2: c
        length: 3
        __proto__: Array[0]
    keys: Array[3]
    length: 3
    ...
```

Comment: Better question: How do I get an Ext.DataView to only display one item? Hard Mode: filtering the store doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output of TestApp.stores.storeMe.data?

Comment: It gives me three items. I added it to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I had:

```
tpl: '<tpl for "."><div class="dataViewItem">ID: {id}<br />Name: {name}<br />Age: {age}</div></tpl>'
```

I needed:

```
tpl: '<tpl for=".">...</tpl>'
```

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't have the json structure with the root called "data"? Try the change your json to:

```
{
    "data": [ {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "sam",
        "age": "4"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "jack",
        "age": "3"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "danny",
        "age": "12"
    } ]
}
```

And put a line -- root: 'data' -- in your reader.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I think it might be something to do with the fact that there's more than one object in the store. When I add a filter, though, it still doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Yoshokatana, that is unlikely.  Are you sure your store contains data?  Try TestApp.stores.storeMe.data.